# different color for different value of a specific column

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have this dataframe:

| giorno | ChiusureNeg | ChiusurePos | close-open | Probabilità | ASKBID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -29 | 34 | 0.1260277590000385 | 0.5396825396825397 | NaN |
| 2 | -21 | 26 | 1.3141801329999225 | 0.5531914893617021 | BID |
| 3 | -28 | 35 | 5.392071843000082 | 0.5555555555555556 | BID |
| 4 | -29 | 19 | -6.59752959299999 | -0.6041666666666666 | ASK |
| 5 | -26 | 21 | -4.095628002000012 | -0.5531914893617021 | ASK |
| 6 | -25 | 22 | 5.528463614999879 | -0.5319148936170213 | NaN |
| 7 | -29 | 35 | 7.13160866299998 | 0.546875 | NaN |
| 8 | -31 | 32 | -1.0534575520001965 | 0.5079365079365079 | NaN |
| 9 | -25 | 22 | -0.882005634999814 | -0.5319148936170213 | NaN |

and I want to plot :

```
pivotD["close-open"].plot(figsize=(30,7),title="titolo",kind='bar')
```

with different color in order the value of ASKBID. Is it possible?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `color` parameter:

```
colors = pivotD['ASKBID'].replace({np.nan: 'blue', 'BID': 'red', 'ASK': 'green'})
pivotD['close-open'].plot(figsize=(30,7), title='titolo', kind='bar', color=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]